Coding preamble issues with apacite style bib
I'm quite new to latex, and lately I started to have some problems with apa citing. here is the code of my preamble and the portrait of the article.
%DISEÑO Y FORMATO DE DOCUMENTO
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{parskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand {\baselinestretch}{2}
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{}

%DATOS BÁSICOS
    \title{Una obra especializada para la Big Band UACh}
\author{Luis Felipe Andrés Uribe Candia}
\date{\today}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{}


%CUERPO DE DOCUMENTO
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\LARGE Universidad Austral de Chile \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\scshape\Large Facultad de Artes Integradas \par}
    \vspace{3cm}
    {\scshape\Huge Una obra especializada para la Big Band UACh \par}
    \vspace{3cm}
    {\itshape\normalsize Entrega final de Anteproyecto de Título \par}
    \vfill
    {\Large Autor: \par}
    {\Large Luis Felipe Andrés Uribe Candia \par}
    \vfill
    {\Large \today \par}
    \end{titlepage}
this is a \cite{gonz2022msc} 
\pagebreak 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{liblib.bib} 
\end{document}

This code was working very well before I have started to use apacite, and it wasn't giving any errors.
now that I have added the cite and the bib code and a simple cite at the end: this is a \cite{gonz2022msc} \pagebreak \bibliographystyle{apacite} \bibliography{liblib.bib} the console gives me a lot of errors that I don't understand at all.
this is the reference i'm using:
@book{gonz2022msc,
    title={M{\'u}sica popular chilena de autor: Industria y ciudadan{\'\i}a a fines del siglo XX},
    author={González, J.{\'A}.},
    isbn={9789561430020},
    url={https://books.google.cl/books?id=JJaLEAAAQBAJ},
    year={2022},
    publisher={Ediciones UC}
} 

before trying apacite, I tried "apa", but in some discussions around they said the apa package is obsolete, and because of that my file was getting corrupted each time I wanted to use the bib system and compile, adding code to my bib files.
Thanks for reading, and I'd be happy to read and try any of your answers. Cheers!

please edit the example that it shows the issue, do not rely on external links

Ok! done. Now the post should be enough to get the same issue in a totally new file with that bib reference

@LFAC.C Try to upvote the answer You liked so much!

You get undefined commands
! Undefined control sequence.
\b@gonz2022msc ...fe@activesfalse \citeauthoryear 

as you have not loaded the latex package that comes with that bibliography style. Adding \useackage{apacite} makes the document run without error.

Thank u so much! this definitely solved my problem. The forums that I've read about starting using apacite never said that I have to load a package before hand. ¿Maybe it's obvious? Anyway, thank u again.

@LFAC.C Try to upvote the answer You liked so much!
